# How to call "Installation alert" window on macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xcode, macos

I have application based on Electron.js and before install it, I have to close some other application so  I tried to looking for information about system "Installation alert" window in google and documentation of electron.js but I didn't find anything.

I have to call system "Installation apert" and pass there list of applications which must be closed before installation starts.
[image]
Can someone help me with this case if it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists no API to present a "Installation Alert". You have to manually retrieve all the running applications and create a custom UI to present the results. I have no idea if that is even possible in Electron, but in Swift you would call `NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications` to get a list of running applications.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications